# Android: dont change when I click in dropdownlist in spinner

Tags: java, android, spinner

When I am trying to use the drop down list of a spinner, the option doesn't select, I was investigating in Google and I think I am configuring the spinner correctly for cities but maybe I have forgotten something in the adapter. I am using a CustomAdapter.

My fragment is:

[image]

In the Fragment call I have this code:

```
ArrayList<ItemPair> data1 = IAndroid.getAllCities();
Spinner spCity = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spPoblacion);
spCity.setAdapter(new ItemPairListAdapter(inflater.getContext(), data1));
```

At the moment I don't have the select click item associated, I only set all items in dropdownlist.

My fragment.xml is:

```
<Spinner
   android:id="@+id/spProvincia"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:clickable="true"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" />
```

My Custom Adapter is:

```
package info.android.adapter;
import info.android.MainActivity;
import info.android.R;    
import java.util.ArrayList;    
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ItemPairListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<info.android.model.ItemPair> navProOffers;

    public ItemPairListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<info.android.model.ItemPair> navProOffers) {
        this.context = context;
        this.navProOffers = navProOffers;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return navProOffers.size();     
    }

    @Override
    public info.android.model.ItemPair getItem(int position) {      
        return navProOffers.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_row_itempair, null);
        }

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {               

          }
        });


        TextView txtKey = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtKey);
        TextView txtValue = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtValue);

        info.android.model.ItemPair ip = getItem(position);

        if (ip != null)
        {
            if (ip.Key != null) txtKey.setText(ip.Key);
            if (ip.Value != null) txtValue.setText(ip.Value);
        }


        convertView.setTag(ip.Key);


        return convertView;
    }
}
```

My ItemPair class is:

```
package info.android.model;

public class ItemPair {
    public String Key;
    public String Value;    
}
```

What is wrong? What do I need to simulate the click behaviour and afterwards receive my item?

Comment: Where is your onItemSelected method?

Comment: Try to remove the `convertView.setOnClickListener(...);` part in the `getView()` method. It might override the default behavior of your spinner.

Comment: where do I have to put in selected item? in adapter? Anyway, I was testing yesterday and it wasnt working, I thought it is automatic.

Comment: G.T, it is working now, it was that, now I can use setOnClickListener. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed click listener in the getView, answered it for G.T.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_row_itempair, null);
        }       

        TextView txtKey = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtKey);
        TextView txtValue = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtValue);

        info.android.model.ItemPair ip = getItem(position);

        if (ip != null)
        {
            if (ip.Key != null) txtKey.setText(ip.Key);
            if (ip.Value != null) txtValue.setText(ip.Value);
        }


        convertView.setTag(ip.Key);


        return convertView;
    }
```